# I have an error with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am building a new app with vuejs 2 and got that error

ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0&bustCache!./src/components/Customers.vue
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/Men'm Elkatan/projects/vuecustomers/src/components/Customers.vue: this is a reserved word (17:6)

I used "this" before but didn't get that error expect today.
Here's my code

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'customers',
  data () {
    return {
      customers: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchCustomers({
      this.$http.get('http://slimapp/api/customers')
        .then(function(response) {
          this.customers = JSON.parse(response.body);
        });
    })
  },
  created: function(){
    this.fetchCustomers();
  }
}
</script>
```

Please!! help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax was wrong. It has to be `fetchCustomers() { ... }`:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'customers',
  data () {
    return {
      customers: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchCustomers() {
      this.$http.get('http://slimapp/api/customers')
        .then(function(response) {
          this.customers = JSON.parse(response.body);
        });
    }
  },
  created: function(){
    this.fetchCustomers();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: OHH !! Thanks a lot, I didn't care for that.